# regex for matching only smaller case letters from a to z

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to do validation for email through javascript for that I have used one regex pattern i.e -

```
 var filter = /[a-z0-9]+\@[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+/;
 alert("match is=="+filter.test(email));
```

I expected that the regex [a-z] will only match alphabets from a-z in lowercase but when i did testing what i expected was wrong..

when i entered `Abc or aBC or @&c or &&&b***` it returns to true...i mean any special character combined with lowercase alphabet a-z or also uppercase alphabet combined with lowercase returns to true..Why is it so?

Please guide someone

Comment: Use anchors: `^` & `$`!

Comment: @RomainPaulus I removed java tag

Comment: why don't you want to match capital letters? email addresses are case insensitive after all

Comment: @OGHaza Nit: the local part of the name (the part before the `@`) is allowed to be case-sensitive by the spec, though of course email providers can choose to treat it as case-insensitive (just as they're allowed to ignore periods, handle aliases, etc). See [RFC 5321 p.41](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#page-42) ("Local-part"). That's not to say it's _wise_ to only allow lowercase letters, of course.

Comment: even more reason to accept caps :P never knew the spec allowed them to be case sensitive at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
var filter = /^[a-z0-9]+\@[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+$/;
alert("match is=="+filter.test(email));
```

Comment: when i used ^[a-z0-9] also it were accepting uppercase and special characters in between for eg. aB%Nkjjhh

Comment: You need the `$` as well.